# deeply nested json validator using cerberus

Tags: json, nested, cerberus

i have a deeply nested json that i'm trying to validate with cerberus.
So, I have the following structure: (NOTE: assume even a deeper nest)

i created my schema for the first level but I cant figure out how to go deeper in the json. I can't manually write the depth schema because I don't know how many levels down the json will be.
As I understand cerberus can handle nested jsons but I can't find any code references for this exact case. Any idea how to implement this?

```
{
"product_number": "123",
"product_version": "ABC",
"subproducts": [
    {
        "product_number": "444",
        "product_version": "ASD",
        "subproducts": [
            {
                "product_number": "666",
                "product_version": "FFF",
                "subproducts": [
                    {
                        "product_number": "888",
                        "product_version": "JUN",
                        "subproducts": []
                    },
                    {
                        "product_number": "644",
                        "product_version": "GYB",
                        "subproducts": [
                            {
                                "product_number": "8890",
                                "product_version": "KLM",
                                "subproducts": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
],}
```

Comment: Hi, I am having similar issue in creating cerberus schema for nested json. How did you managed it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [schema registry](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/schemas.html#registries) for self-referencing schemas:

```
from cerberus import schema_registry, Validator

product_schema = {
    "product_number": {"type": "string", "regex": "\d+"},
    "product_version": {"type": "string", "regex": "[A-Z]+"},
    "subproducts": {"type": "list", "schema": "product_schema"}
}

schema_registry.add("product_schema", product_schema)
validator = Validator(product_schema)
```

Answer (score -1):

The "$ref" keyword defined in the JSON Schema Specification may fit your needs.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["product_number", "product_version", "subproducts"],
    "properties": {
        "product_number": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "product_version": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subproducts": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "$ref": "#"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the properties `"product_number"` and `"product_version"` are required if and only if the sibling `"subproducts"` is not empty, the JSON schema should be modified as shown below:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["subproducts"],
    "properties": {
        "subproducts": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "$ref": "#"
            }
        }
    },
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "subproducts": {
                    "maxItems": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "required": ["product_number", "product_version"],
            "properties": {
                "subproducts": {
                    "minItems": 1
                },
                "product_number": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "product_version": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i'm mainly aiming for CERBERUS only here. my json is a bit more complicated than what i posted. the field "subproducts" is an array and ONLY if it's NOT EMPTY, i have to check if other fields are present in the same level as subproducts. This is a custom rule that i was only able to make in Cerberus. unless you know a way to do this in json schema???

Comment: alright i definitely can't use jsonschema. it's incompatible with my other libraries. i can only use it up to draft4.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not familiar with Cerberus and its unique schema language. So I cannot help you.